# Xamarin Android Tabs Without ActionBar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

> How To Hide/Remove Action-bar Without Hiding A Tabs Layout

[image: How To Hide/Remove Action-bar Without Hiding A Tabs Layout]

> MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        string[] AllTabs = { "First Tab", "Second Tab" };
```

> Navigation Mode

```
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        var pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
        var adaptor = new GenericFragmentPagerAdaptor(SupportFragmentManager);

        adaptor.AddFragmentView((i, v, b) =>
        {
            var view = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, v, false);
            var textsample = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtText);
            textsample.Text = "This is First Page";
            return view;
        });

        adaptor.AddFragmentView((i, v, b) =>
        {
            var view = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, v, false);
            var textsample = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtText);
            textsample.Text = "This is Second Page";
            return view;
        });


        pager.Adapter = adaptor;
        pager.SetOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPagerListenerForActionBar(ActionBar));
        for (int j = 0; j < AllTabs.Length; j++)
        {
            ActionBar.AddTab(pager.GetViewPageTab(ActionBar, AllTabs[j])); 
        }
    }
}
```

> When i use ActionBar.Hide() Everything(ActionBar And Tabs) Are Hide.
>
> I Use :

```
public class GenericFragmentPagerAdaptor : FragmentPagerAdapter
```

> And

```
public class GenericViewPagerFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
```

**I Want To Hide This Part**

[image: My Example]

Comment: Has the issue be resolved?

Comment: I Create New Project And i rewrite a code with another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i use ActionBar.Hide() Everything(ActionBar And Tabs) Are Hide.

Because the tabs are a part of the action bar. When you are hidding the action bar, you are hidding everything.

> How To Hide/Remove Action-bar Without Hiding A Tabs Layout.

You can achieve that by using following codes:

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

This will hide the title bar part of the action bar.